# Angular - Validate the Current Page before going to Next Step in Angular-Archwizard

Tags: angular

I am using Angular-7. I am using angular-archwizard for make multi-step form, currently it allows me to go to next step without entering all value of required field, I don't want to allow that, I want to go next step if I entered value in all required field.

```
<form class="form-clientquote" #clientquoteForm=ngForm (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <aw-wizard #wizard [navBarLayout]="'large-empty-symbols'">
  <aw-wizard-step [stepTitle]="'Transaction Details'" [navigationSymbol]="{ symbol: '&#xf085;', fontFamily: 'FontAwesome' }">
  <div class="centered-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
      <label for="quote_origin" >Origin<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quote_origin" google-place
                                (onSelect)="setAddress($event)" placeholder="Origin" name="quote_origin" [(ngModel)]="form.quote_origin" #quote_origin="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : quote_origin.invalid && ((quote_origin.dirty || quote_origin.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)}"   required>
      <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="quote_origin.invalid && ((quote_origin.dirty || quote_origin.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="quote_origin.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Origin is required.</div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <label for="quote_destination">Destination<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quote_destination" google-place
                                (onSelect)="setAddress($event)" placeholder="Destination" name="quote_destination" [(ngModel)]="form.quote_destination" #quote_destination="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : quote_destination.invalid && ((quote_destination.dirty || quote_destination.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)}"   required>
                                <!-- <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                                  <li *ngFor="let key of addrKeys">
                                    <span style="font-weight: bold">{{key}}</span>: <span>{{addr[key]}}</span>
                                  </li>
                                </ul> -->
                                <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="quote_destination.invalid && ((quote_destination.dirty || quote_destination.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
                                  <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="quote_destination.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Destination is required.</div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                             </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                  <label for="commodity">Commodity<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="commodity" placeholder="Commodity" name="commodity" [(ngModel)]="form.commodity" #commodity="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : commodity.invalid && ((commodity.dirty || commodity.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)}"   required>
                                  <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="commodity.invalid && ((commodity.dirty || commodity.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="commodity.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Commodity is required.</div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                  <label for="truck_type">Truck Type<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>
                                  <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" [(ngModel)]="form.truck_type" #truckType="ngModel" name="truck_type" required>
                                    <option [ngValue]="null">Choose a Truck Type</option>
                                      <option [ngValue]="truck_type" *ngFor="let truck_type of truck_types">{{truck_type}}</option>
                                    </select>
                                   <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="truckType.invalid && ((truckType.dirty || truckType.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)">
                                    <div style="color:red;" class="alert alert-danger">Truck Type is required.</div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                               </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="truck_required">Required Truck(s)<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>
                                    <input type="number" (keypress)="numberOnly($event)" class="form-control" id="truck_required" placeholder="1,2,3..." min="1" max="20" name="truck_required" [(ngModel)]="form.truck_required" #truck_required="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : truck_required.invalid && ((truck_required.dirty || truck_required.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)}" required maxlength="2">
                                    <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="truck_required.invalid && ((truck_required.dirty || truck_required.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
                                      <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="truck_required.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Required Truck(s) is required.</div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                                      <label for="loading_date">Loading Date<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>
                                      <div class="input-group date" style="width: 100%;" >
                                          <mat-form-field>
                                            <input matInput [matDatepicker] = "picker" placeholder = "Choose a date" name="loading_date" [(ngModel)]="form.loading_date" #loading_date="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : loading_date.invalid && ((loading_date.dirty || loading_date.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)}"   required>
                                            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for] = "picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                                            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                                         </mat-form-field>
                                        <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="loading_date.invalid && ((loading_date.dirty || loading_date.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)">
                                            <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="loading_date.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Loading Date is required.</div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                  </div>
                                 </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                                     <div class="col-xs-12">
                                     <label for="comment">Comment</label>
                                     <input class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" type="textarea" id="comment" name="comment" [(ngModel)]="form.comment" #comment="ngModel" >
                                  </div>
                                 </div>
                               </div>

                               <br>
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" awNextStep> Next ></button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                    </aw-wizard-step>

                    <aw-wizard-step [stepTitle]="'Personal Details'" [navigationSymbol]="{ symbol: '&#xf0b1;', fontFamily: 'FontAwesome' }">
                      <div class="centered-content">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xs-12">
                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <label for="first_name">First Name<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" [(ngModel)]="form.first_name" #first_name="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : first_name.invalid && ((first_name.dirty || first_name.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)}"   required>
                            <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="first_name.invalid && ((first_name.dirty || first_name.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="first_name.errors?.required" class="alert alert-danger">First Name is required.</div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <label for="last_name">Last Name<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" [(ngModel)]="form.last_name" #last_name="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : last_name.invalid && ((last_name.dirty || last_name.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)}"   required>
                            <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="last_name.invalid && ((last_name.dirty || last_name.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
                              <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="last_name.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Last Name is required.</div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                         </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                              <label for="business_name">Business Name<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="business_name" placeholder="Business Name" name="business_name" [(ngModel)]="form.business_name" #business_name="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : business_name.invalid && ((business_name.dirty || business_name.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)}"   required>
                              <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="business_name.invalid && ((business_name.dirty || business_name.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
                                <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="business_name.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Business Name is required.</div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                              <label for="address">Office Address</label>
                              <input class="form-control" google-place
                              (onSelect)="setAddress($event)"placeholder="address" type="text" id="address" name="address" [(ngModel)]="form.address" #address="ngModel" >
                          </div>
                           </div>
                          </div>        
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                           <div class="col-xs-6">
                              <label for="phone">Phone<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                                  </div>
                                  <input type="text" 
                                  class="form-control" 
                                  id="phone" 
                                  placeholder="Phone" 
                                  name="phone" 
                                  [(ngModel)]="form.phone" 
                                  #phone="ngModel" 
                                  pattern="^[+-]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*"
                                  [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : phone.invalid && ((phone.dirty || phone.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)}"   
                                  required maxlength="14">
                                </div>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback" 
                                [hidden]="phone.valid || phone.untouched">
                                <div  style="color:red;" *ngIf="phone.errors && phone.errors.required">
                                    Phone number is required
                                </div>
                                <div  style="color:red;" *ngIf="phone.errors && phone.errors.pattern">
                                    Valid Phone number is invalid
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                              <label for="email">Email<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>
                              <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                  <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" 
                                class="form-control" 
                                id="email" 
                                placeholder="Email" 
                                name="email" 
                                [(ngModel)]="form.email" 
                                #email="ngModel" 
                                pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$"
                                [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : email.invalid && ((email.dirty || email.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)}"   
                                required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-feedback" class="invalid-feedback" 
                            [hidden]="email.valid || email.untouched">
                            <div  style="color:red;" *ngIf="email.errors && email.errors.required">
                                Email is required
                            </div>
                            <div  style="color:red;" *ngIf="email.errors && email.errors.pattern">
                                Valid Email is invalid
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            </div>
                           </div>
                          </div>
                          <br>

                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                  <button style="margin:5px"  type="button" class="btn btn-warning" awPreviousStep>< Previous</button>
                                  <button style="margin:5px" (keyup.enter)="onSubmit()" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" awNextStep> Get A Quote</button>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                    </aw-wizard-step>
                        <br>
                        <aw-wizard-step [stepTitle]="'Success'" [navigationSymbol]="{ symbol: '&#xf00c;', fontFamily: 'FontAwesome' }">
                          <div class="centered-content">
                            <br>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">

                            </div>
                         </div>
                       </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                  <!-- <button style="margin:5px"  type="button" class="btn btn-warning" awPreviousStep>< Previous</button>
                                  <button style="margin:5px"  type="submit" class="btn btn-success" > Send Quote</button> -->
                                  <!-- <button style="margin:5px"  class="btn btn-success" type="button" href="/landing">Title on button</button> -->
                                  <a style="margin:5px" routerLink="/landing" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-home margin-right-10px"></i>
                                    Home 
                                </a>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                          </div>
                        </aw-wizard-step>
                  </aw-wizard> 
  </form>
```

I have three steps:

1. Step-1: Transaction Detail
2. Step-2: Personal Detail
3. Step-3: Success and Feedback Page.

This is what I want to achieve:

1. I want step-1 to be validated before going to Step-2
2. I want step-2 to save into database.
3. I want step-3 to display success message and show detail of the data submitted into database.
4. I want to disallow the user from clicking on the stepTitle (disable it).

[image: diagram]

So far, I have been able to save into the database. How do I achieve these?

Answer (score 0):

**You can disable the button while the formGroup is invalid:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" awNextStep [disabled]="yourFormGroup.invalid"> Next ></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// At the top of my component class that implements the <wizard>
@ViewChild(WizardComponent)
public wizard: WizardComponent;


Submit(){
  this.submittedStep1 = true;
  if(this.form.valid){
    this.wizard.goToNextStep();
  }
}
// then later, this works great

 <button type="button" uiSref="work" class="btn btn-primary ml-2" (click)="SubmitUpload()">Next <i class="ft-chevron-right"></i></button>
```